# Seed multiple tables with one statement in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I am trying to update multiple tables using one statement in EF.

I have 3 tables `Category`, `SubCategory` and `Details`. This is sample code I am trying to use:

```
if (context.Categories.Where(C => C.Code == 1).FirstOrDefault() == null)
{
    context.Categories.Add(new Data.Category() { Code = 1, Description = "First Category" });
    context.SubCategories.Add(new Data.SubCategory() { SubCode = 1, Description = "First SubCategory", CategoryCode = C.Code });
    context.Details.Add(new Data.Detail() { Code = 1, Description = "First Details", DetailCode = SubCode });
}
```

As you can tell I am only learning EF and any help or advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to have a data model that allows that. Something like this:

```
public class Category
{
   public int Code {get;set;}
   public List<SubCategory> SubCategories {get;set;}
}

public class SubCategory
{
   public int SubCode {get;set;}
   public int ParentCode {get;set;}
   public Category ParentCategory {get;set;}
}
```

Than you can insert object with it's related objects in one EF statement:

```
var category = new Category
{
   Code = 1,
   SubCategories = new List<SubCategory>{new SubCategory{SubCode = 1}}
}

dbContext.Categories.Add(category);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

EF will make a connection between parent and it's child using child's `ParentCode` property. ParentCategory property is navigational property for child's object allowing you to easily get it's parent.